# How to generate text in javascript containg escape characters

Tags: jquery

I am trying to generate the following text through javascript

```
http:\\24.157.150.93:8080\......\json={"location": "123","screen": "456","ident": "789"}
```

I have tried as following

```
var url = "24.157.150.93:8080" ;
var location = "123";
var screen = "456" ;
var ident = "789";

var text = "http:\\"+url+"\......\json={"'location'": '"+location+"',"'screen'": '"+screen+"',"'ident'": '"+ident+"'}";

alert(text);
```

But i am getting

Uncaught SyntaxError: **Unexpected string  under browser console**

Sorry that i Couldn't post jsfiddle link  as its not allowing me to save this content also

Could anybody please help me how to generate the above string with the specified input values ??

Comment: Any specific reason you are trying to use backslashes in a URL? And it looks like you forgot to escape quotes.

Comment: @TimSeguine the text will be used to generate QR code .

Comment: Ok, I am not sure what that has to do with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
var text = "http:\\"+"\\"+url+"\\......\\json={"+'"location"'+": "+location+","+'"screen"'+": "+screen+","+'"ident"'+": "+ident+"}";
```

Comment: Perfect , Thanks , except that quotes are missing for the values

Comment: Thanks, you can try this for quotes missing : var text = "http:\\"+"\\"+url+"\\......\\json={"+'"location"'+": "+"\""+location+"\""+","+'"screen"'+": "+"\""+screen+"\""+","+'"ident"'+": "+"\""+ident+"\""+"}";

Comment: @DavidMaw FYI, if you surround code with backticks(`\``) in comments, it is a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be:

```
var text = "http://"+url+"/....../json="+encodeURIComponent("{\"location\": \""+location+"\",\"screen\": \""+screen+"\",\"ident\": \""+ident+"\"}");
```

URLs use forward slashes, not backslashes, and conformant JSON requires the use of double quotes, not single quotes. You should also URL encode JSON data if it is being sent in a URL. And I am guessing you either forgot the `?` character in your URL to start a query string, or the `#` to start an anchor.

If you, however, want it to give you *exactly* the text you asked for in your post it would look like this:

```
var text =  "http:\\\\"+url+"\\......\\json={\"location\": \""+location+"\",\"screen\": \"+screen+\",\"ident\": \""+ident+"\"}";
```

There is no real trick to it except you have to replace wherever you want a `"` character with `\"` and wherever you want a `\` with `\\`